# VBA code delete the row of noisy data

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub project()
    Dim a, deltat_value1, deltat_value2, deltat_value3 As Integer
    a = 2
    Do
        deltat_value1 = Cells(a, 7).Value
        deltat_value2 = Cells(a + 1, 7).Value
        deltat_value3 = Cells(a + 2, 7).Value
        If Abs(deltat_value1 - deltat_value2) > 5 And Abs(deltat_value2 - deltat_value3) > 5 Then
        Rows(a + 1).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
        a = a + 1
    Loop Until deltat_value1 = 14700
End Sub
```

I am trying to delete the noisy data, I set if a data point that it has a difference bigger than 5 from both the points above and below it, that is a noisy data and I set to delete the whole row of the noisy data.
However, I am having this problem for the line:

```
deltat_value3=Cells(a+2,7).Value
Runtime Error 1004 "Application-defined or Object-defined error"
```

And the running takes extremely longer time. I am a new user of VBA programming and I think my method may be inefficient, there may be other ways work much better, any advice?

Comment: It looks like the problem could be that you are declaring `deltat_value3 as Integer`. You probably don't realize it but you have declared the other variables as `Variant` data types, which can accept multiple data types.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
Sub ytrewq()
    Dim a As Long, deltat_value1 As Long, deltat_value2 As Long, deltat_value3 As Long
    Dim rKill As Range

    a = 2
    Do
        deltat_value1 = Cells(a, 7).Value
        deltat_value2 = Cells(a + 1, 7).Value
        deltat_value3 = Cells(a + 2, 7).Value
        If Abs(deltat_value1 - deltat_value2) > 5 And Abs(deltat_value2 - deltat_value3) > 5 Then
            If rKill Is Nothing Then
               Set rKill = Cells(a + 1, 1)
            Else
               Set rKill = Union(rKill, Cells(a + 1, 1))
            End If
        End If
        a = a + 1
    Loop Until deltat_value1 = 14700

    rKill.EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. But I am still having the same problem, I tried to dim variables with integer, variant, long, double and so on, it doesn't work at all. The error shows at the line of                     deltat_value3=Cells(a+2,7).Value:
Runtime Error 1004 "Application-defined or Object-defined error"                       I even tried only two variables (deltat_value1 and deltat_value2). The same problem happens again for deltat_value2, similiar code works before, I have no idea why this code doesn't work.